# Something not defined as it is under an "if"

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
if "stockStatus" in res.text:
  data = json.loads(res.text)
  stock_status = data["stockStatus"]
  name = data["name"]
  prod_url = data["URL"]

else:
 print("Product not yet loaded or removed: " + pid)
 pass

if stock_status == "IN STOCK":
 #rest of code
```

The problem is `stock_status` is defined under the `if` so when I run the script it throws error that `stock_status` isn't defined. Is there any way of making it so `stock_status` is defined not just under that `if` because it needs to be there for the rest of my script to work. Thanks.

Comment: Define `stock_status` in the `else` block as well.

Comment: it's not defined just under the if.. it's in the same scope as the rest of the code.. functions and classes create new scopes but just a conditional or loop **does not**

Comment: You only need a `pass` in an `else` (or other block scope) if the block would otherwise be empty. It's not needed in the `else`.

Comment: so why would I be getting ```NameError: name 'stock_status' is not defined``` then? @0TTT0

Comment: if the `else` is executed, then it is never defined

Answer (score 5):

You can just initialize `stock_status` as `None` before the if statement:

```
stock_status = None

if "stockStatus" in res.text:
    data = json.loads(res.text)
    stock_status = data["stockStatus"]
    name = data["name"]
    prod_url = data["URL"]
else:
    print("Product not yet loaded or removed: " + pid)
    pass

if stock_status == "IN STOCK":
    #rest of code
```

Comment: Haha... Ok Upvote. I'd figure the question would get closed as duplicate somewhere...